# Arranging Images Randomly In Order

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have a list of images with various sizes and I have to show them all in a page. I want to arrange them in such a way that no white spaces are shown between images on oneline and the image on the next line. Anyways I can achieve this using CSS and Javascript, ??

Following is the example on jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zHxPT/1/

Comment: This is not possible unless you want the pictures to overlap each other?

Comment: Would prefer if they didnt overlap each other. Can you give the code where they overlap each other ??

Comment: Are you looking for a BEST FIT algorithm - a bit like clothes makes are using to utilise as much of a piece of cloth as possible? Or something like http://highslide.com/

Comment: Kinda yes mplungjan. If thats the only way to achieve it.

Comment: I found http://highslide.com/ but you can run over all the images, find the largest (tallest or wides) and resize all images to same height OR same width

Comment: @Zaj see my answer. BTW use `@` to notify people when you comment on their comment otherwise most chances are they won't see your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to have the images overlap each other you can have minimum gap between them using client side code to position the items dynamically:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oList = document.getElementById("liParent")
    var arrItems = oList.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var totalWidth = parseInt(oList.style.width, 10);
    var curLeft = 0;
    var curTop = 0;
    var arrHeights = new Array();
    var colIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
        var oCurItem = arrItems[i];
        var oImage = oCurItem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        oCurItem.style.position = "absolute";
        var curWidth = oImage.offsetWidth;
        var curHeight = oImage.offsetHeight;
        if (curLeft + curWidth > totalWidth) {
            curLeft = 0;
            colIndex = 0;
        }
        if (colIndex < arrHeights.length)
            curTop = arrHeights[colIndex];
        oCurItem.style.left = curLeft + "px";
        oCurItem.style.top = curTop + "px";
        arrHeights[colIndex] = (curHeight + curTop);
        curLeft += curWidth;
        colIndex++;
    }
}
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zHxPT/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jquery?

With CSS you could set the margin and padding of the elements to 0. Then use javascript as an array, get a random number and write that index to the page.

Comment: Joseph i dont want pick images randomly and display them. I have a list of images which i need to display properly in such a way that there isnt any space between images on one line and the images on next line,

Comment: Oh I see. I misread what you wanted. I would suggest using css to ensure all of the images are the same size and use a div to house them, with the images being dropped in one after the other inside of it. 

<div id="container">
<img id="noSpaceImages"><img id="noSpaceImages"><img id="noSpaceImages">
</div>

CSS:

width:xx%;
height:xx%;
margin:0;
padding:0;

Try out something like that. 

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Load the images (in a hidden div if needed) then find the tallest and give all the images the same height. That way there will be no gap to the next row (and then show the div)

For example

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Hey thats an option i gave a thought to, but the images resolution goes for a toss with that hence didnt want to do it.

Comment: It is the simplest - you could group the images by name in small medium and large and never show small next to large...