# Arranging Divs to minimize spaces

Tags: css, layout, html, grid, css-float

Here's my problem: I have a group of divs which have varying amounts of content. They're floated left and I want them to line up so there's no vertical space between them (apart from the 10px margin I added.

here's an example on  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sifiskip/D23KU/2/)

it's a bit like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843064/arranging-images-randomly-in-order) but i couldn't quite follow the suggestions

1st, is this possible? CSS or jQuery? If you know how to do this, please explain it to me.

Thanks

Si-Fi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s not possible just with css, although I saw a sort of a solution using css3 columns but that´s not very cross-browser compatible.

You´ll have to use javascript, for example the [Masonry jquery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/?resources/jquery-masonry).

Comment: Thanks! That looks like exactly what I need. I figured it couldn't be done with css but I was really hoping you could.

Answer (score 0):

Only one think what you can do here closer:

[***Click here***](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/D23KU/3/)

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I wanted it to do. @jeroen has suggested something that looks perfect. 

Actually, I'll use this as well as a fallback in case the user doesn't have javascript enabled. It looks much cleaner.